# Tomcat: Generated context-path is different for cloned application in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-3, server.xml, contextroot

I've been trying to merge few different projects in to a single one in eclipse. In this attempt I've tried this following steps which causes the context path to be generated differently(incorrectly?).

**Core-Problem:**

1. Copied a dynamic web project (Maven) in eclipse and paste as a new project
   (Cloned-duplicate)
2. Add the project to embedded Tomcat server in
   eclipse.
3. Go to Tomcat Server project in eclipse and open server.xml
4. Generated     <    Context    > tag contains the following

   ```
   <Context docBase="DuplicateApp" path="App" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DuplicateApp"/>
   ```

   I would've expected both 'path' and 'docBase' to point to DuplicateApp, which is the name of the cloned app, however it is appearing incorrect. Is this even expected behavior?

Quite a bit of searching confirms my learning that both 'path & 'docbase' should point to the name of the web application/war file name.

**Additional Information:**

1. Eclipse Juno Java EE version installed
2. M2E plugin installed in Eclipse
3. Tomcat version 7
4. pom.xml did not override war name - cross checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After desperately refreshing to find no answer to my post, found answer to my own question after few additional hours of slogging!

There seems to be a property named 'Web Project Settings' which can be accessed via Project > properties > 'Web Project Settings'  where context root can be changed. Not sure how this get populated or where it is retained just as yet. But atleast this solves my problem!